# loop through data validation list and carry out print macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Data validation list which contains Names of Employees each month i manually go through each one and press a print button with the following macro.

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Cells.Range("B1") & " Period " & Cells.Range("J1")

strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
    From:=1, _
    To:=2


End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

This Prints the sheet out to the pathway where the workbook is saved.

My Data Validation List is in Cell 'B1' Is there a way i can use VBA to loop through the list and print these for me? I Have not been able to really get going doing a draft as using a data validation list in vba is completely new to me.

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()

Dim Name As Variant
'Dim List As ListBox?

For Each Name in List
  Call PDFActiveSheet
Next
```

Comment: How is the DV list set up? A literal comma delimited string, or using a Range?

Comment: Its set up as a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()

    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range

    Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

    Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
        Call PDFActiveSheet
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: revised code based on comments below:

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()

    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range

    Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

    Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
        Call PDFActiveSheet
    Next
End Sub
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim myFile                As Variant
    Dim strFile               As String
    Dim sFolder               As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'enter name and select folder for file
    ' start in current workbook folder
    strFile = ws.Range("B1").Value & " Period " & ws.Range("J1").Value

    sFolder = GetFolder()
    If sFolder = "" Then
        MsgBox "No folder selected. Code will terminate."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    myFile = sFolder & "\" & strFile

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
            From:=1, _
            To:=2

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    dlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    dlg.Title = "Select folder to save PDFs"
    If dlg.Show = -1 Then
        GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It works ok, it generates the save as box which just needs to hit enter to save (Not a problem).

Although once I run it, it doesnt stop until i have gone through each value in the DV list, is there a way to stop it if the Red Cross is clicked/Cancel?

And also could there be a way to press OK automatically as it goes through each one as it would do it at a more programming speed than human speed of clicking ok 102 times?

Comment: @MatthewBond If you don't want to prompt for the file name you could just remove that part - do you still want the original code for a one off PDF run?

Comment: It prompts the save, the file name changes with the value in B1 (as in original code) so when i run the code it used to prompt me for each one to save which is what it still does now.  

so using what you've given me it runs through each one, but on a one by one basis of pressing save each time, how could that be avoided so the code automatically runs through each one (as it does now) but saves it instead of prompting?

Comment: @MatthewBond My question is do you still want to be prompted for the save if you run the original macro as a one off?

Comment: oh i see, if possible id like it to just save all from the one prompt

Comment: But the prompt changes based on B1 so that couldn't work. Do you just want to choose a **folder**, rather than a file name?

Comment: If you could that would be great and il give it a go

Comment: OK I've posted a revised version of the full code you need.

Comment: Thank you, your help is much appreciated