# Loop through a data validation list selecting multiple worksheets to print to PDF or excel

Tags: excel, vba, validation, printing

So I found this code and it is super close to what I am needing. [loop through data validation list and carry out print macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529571/loop-through-data-validation-list-and-carry-out-print-macro)
My issue is I have 4 worksheets I want them all included in the PDF output. I currently have a data validation drop down in A6 that updates the data on all 4 worksheets when selected. The above code only populates the first worksheet when I run the VBA macro.

Comment: Please refer to the following page on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide the code you are using along with data, the results you are getting and also the expected results.

Comment: As said above, please add some code, data and actual vs expected result in your question. Nethertheless, it seems you only need to add a loop through your sheets and you'll be fine.